# What exactly is a black screen with blinking cursor while booting?

Tags: boot

I mean that screen we can observe when PC boots. Does it have a name? Can we actually type something in? Why does the cursor move one line down before loading proceeds? I can't even google it out.

[image: That screen]

Comment: You cannot type anything, what Operating system you have?

Comment: You're right, I can't type, but why is there a cursor then? I'm just wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different origins this could be from depending on the combination of hardware and software you have installed in your system.

If I had to guess I would say that the cursor you are seeing is being drawn by the BIOS or the bootloader.

During an UEFI boot some motherboards have a basic prompt that you can get to and type commands before any software is loaded from a disk. This program resides in the UEFI BIOS.

SEE:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/uefi-shell

I'm not aware of anything like this that exists for a legacy MBR boot.

I've seen a motherboard that displays a blinking cursor between the POST and the RAID setup menu. This is being displayed by the BIOS. It is not a prompt.

The Windows bootloader may also display a blinking cursor at times. This may have it's roots in DOS or the old NT code but it is also not a prompt.

WINDOWS SPECIFIC INFORMATION:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcd-system-store-settings-for-uefi#windowsbootloader

For more information about the boot process and what the steps are called:

http://www.opsschool.org/en/latest/boot_process_101.html